# new with multiple arguments in cppreference example

Tags: c++, new-operator

From [cppreference's `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) page.

> ```
> new T;      // calls operator new(sizeof(T))
>            // (C++17) or operator new(sizeof(T), std::align_val_t(alignof(T))))
> new T[5];   // calls operator new[](sizeof(T)*5 + overhead)
>            // (C++17) or operator new(sizeof(T)*5+overhead, >std::align_val_t(alignof(T))))
> new(2,f) T; // calls operator new(sizeof(T), 2, f)
>            // (C++17) or operator new(sizeof(T), std::align_val_t(alignof(T)), 2, f)
> ```

What does `new(2, f) T;` do?

Comment: Useful supplementary reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: you can define custom `new` operator with custom args: `struct T { void* operator new(size_t s, int x, double f); };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does `new(2, f) T;` do?

That second argument in placement-new can be used to pass a parameter to your custom `T::operator new` implementation.

Here is a toy example that triggers it (in the output, you can see that the parameter `f=42.0`is passed to `T::operator new`):

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct T {
  T() {
    std::cout << "T::T called\n";
  }

  void* operator new(size_t s, int x, double f) {
    std::cout << "T::new called with s=" << s << ", x=" << x << ", f=" << f << '\n';
    return malloc(x * s);
  }

  char data[512];
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "new T[5]:\n";
  new T[5];

  double f = 42.0;
  std::cout << "\nnew(2, f) T:\n";
  new(2, f) T;
}
```

Output:

```
new T[5]:
T::T called
T::T called
T::T called
T::T called
T::T called

new(2, f) T:
T::new called with s=512, x=2, f=42
T::T called
```

Answer (score -4):

Be careful using tricks like this from examples online, they often are terrible.

The `new` keyword in C++ is shorthand for the following in C.

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} Foo;

Foo *makeFoo(int a) {
    Foo *foo = (Foo *)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    foo->a = a;
}
```

The `malloc` function reserves memory for that object, signaling it will be used as a pointer. The `new` operator does the same, but defaults `sizeof(Foo)`. The parameters you see are the result of `sizeof` and an `align_val_t` instance.

Comment: That is not the only thing. New also formally brings the object to life. The malloc-based example does not (you would need it to be `Foo *foo = new (malloc(sizeof(Foo)) Foo;` - but this does not account for possible misalignment).

Comment: @spectras The example I used was in C. The `new` keyword is unique to C++.

Comment: Isn't it the point? Object lifetime is at the core of the question, and C does not even have the concept of an object lifetime separate from storage duration, making it ill-chosen to answer the question.